# VsCode Dev Containers + Rootless Docker = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

Wondering if anyone has been able to overcome this error message in Visual Studio Code while using the [Dev Containers extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/tutorial) and [Rootless Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/):

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Exact output from Visual Studio Code:

[image]

**Environment**:

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Visual Studio Code 1.85.1
- Docker Engine Community 24.0.7

**What I have tried**:

- Set the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable in `/etc/profile.d/my_env_vars.sh` (I made sure to re-login after setting the variable): `export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock`
- Create a symlink to `/run/user/1000/docker.sock`: `ln -s /run/user/1000/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock`
- Install the [VsCode Docker extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/overview) then set the `DOCKER_HOST` variable to: `unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock`
- Verify Docker is operational: `docker run hello-world`

  Hello from Docker!
  This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

  To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:

  1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
  2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
     (amd64)
  3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
     executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
  4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
     to your terminal.
- Verify the Active Context: `docker context ls`

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will fix your problem, but I had a similar issue. What resolved it was the following (not sure which step actually fixed the issue):

- Upgrading vscode from 1.77.3 to 1.85.1 (probably not related considering your version)
- Reloading some extensions especially Remote - SSH
- Updating all packages `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Hope this helps.